# Storing vector of variable-size structs in a binary file in c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, binary

I am attempting to read and write a vector of structs into a file. Iterating through each struct, first I write the size of the following struct, then I write the structure. I encounter crashes when reading the file.

Structure:

```
struct Book {

   string author;
   string title;
   string isbn;
   int copies;
   Status status;

};
```

Loading from file:

```
void load_books(vector<Book> *books) {
ifstream readFile;
int read_size;
Book temp;

readFile.open(BOOK_DB_FILE.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary) ;

while(readFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&read_size), sizeof(read_size))) {
    cout << read_size << endl;

    if (!readFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&temp), read_size)) {
        cout << "Failed to read library.dat!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Attempting to load book..." << endl;
    cout << temp.title << ":" << temp.copies << endl;

    (*books).push_back(temp);

}
cout << "Loaded books!" << endl;

}
```

Writing to file:

```
void save_books(vector<Book> *books) {
ofstream writeFile;
int write_size;

writeFile.open(BOOK_DB_FILE.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);

for (int ind = 0 ; ind < (*books).size(); ind++) {
    Book book = (*books)[ind];
    write_size = sizeof(book);

    cout << "Writing book with size: " << write_size << endl;
    cout << book.copies << " of " << book.title << " by " << book.author << endl;

    writeFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&write_size), sizeof(write_size));
    writeFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(books + ind), write_size);
}

}
```

Comment: Note: The crash occurs right after 
cout << "Attempting to load book..." << endl;
is called...

Comment: I strongly recommend you take a look at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: This is for a class project, and I'm not allowed to use boost.

Comment: Why oh why do they give these "binary file" writing / reading assignments, when it will not work?  Your `Book` is not a POD type, thus it cannot be written to a binary file in the fashion that you're writing it.  You cannot write `Book` in just a binary blob like that -- it has to be serialized, meaning you must write the *data* to the file, not the object.  (I see this question or variations of it over and over again, especially from students).

Comment: Is it the string inclusion that prevents it from being a POD? I was under the impression that I could serialize it like so if I preceded it with the size of the struct.

Comment: @Kerem The `sizeof` is a compile-time value.  The `sizeof` knows nothing about how much data your string is using at runtime.  If you want proof, write a `Book` object with 50 or so characters for the string members.  Open the file you wrote in an editor -- can you identify where the string is, or do you just see junk where the string data is supposed to be?  I bet it's junk.

Comment: @Kerem  Also `sizeof(Book)` -- [see here](http://ideone.com/ajdwx2).  Note that the value is the same before and after one of the strings is populated.  The `sizeof` just gives you the size of the type, in bytes, and type `Book` is 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would always recommend to use a library such as [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), but alas, you're not allowed to use Boost (or any other serialization library, I guess).  So we'll look at your current approach instead.

While your method of dumping the binary object layout straight to disk is fraught with risk (e.g. because of platform dependencies like endianness), I'll assume that for a mere class project we can live with these deficiencies.

Your main problem, right now, is that you are dumping the `struct Book` memory representation to disk and reading it back in, but you are overlooking the fact that the `std::string` fields are not handled like that.

Internally, `std::string` is *not a POD*, but (roughly) another class which allocates *separate* memory for the actual string data (for sake of illustration, assume it carries a `char*` pointer in its implementation).  You are currently not storing this data; you are only storing the values of `std::string`'s internal pointers, and reading them back when loading.  At that point, these internal pointers are pointing nowhere meaningful.

For a rough idea of what you need to do, you will have to explicitly and individually serialize/deserialize all members of your `Book` class recursively.  Roughly like this:

1. Store the length, and the raw string data of `author`
2. Store the length, and the raw string data of `title`
3. Store the length, and the raw string data of `isbn`
4. Store the integer `copies`
5. Store the enum value of `status`

And when reading, load every member in the same way.  So you will need a serialzer/deserializer function for every "basic" type (in your case, `std::string`, `int` and `Status`), and "combining" serializer and deserializer functions for `Book` which call the base members' serialization/deserialization functions in turn.

This is also roughly what Boost.Serialization does internally, so I recommend you have a look at it anyway. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm also assuming I could use a c-string in the Book struct instead.

Comment: Of course you could use a c-string, and then it would be obvious that it's a pointer and that serializing a pointer doesn't make much sense, right? I would stick with `std::string`, though; it's the proper C++ type choice, and you have to write special (de)serialization code either way.

Comment: I'd imagine using a c-string would work, as the ofstream::write method takes a pointer anyways?

Comment: Either way, I've implemented what you mentioned and it works.